# Taxi application development-Can I replicate the following details to my database from an API

Tags: web, uber-api

I am developing a new taxi application for my client. Now I want to integrate API from Uber, lyft, and madallion to the application. Are these APIs able to pull the transaction details, driver profiles, driver schedules, Rating etc to my application database?

Answer (score 2):

Uber's API documentation lists its publicly available endpoints here: [httsp://developer.uber.com/docs/api-overview](http://httsp://developer.uber.com/docs/api-overview)

Uber does not have public endpoints with drivers' profiles, transaction details and ratings available yet.

Please note that Uber's [terms of service](https://developer.uber.com/docs/terms-of-use) prohibit aggregating Uber with competitors. From that link:

> Be a strong, trustworthy partner to Uber. Please do not:
>
> - Compete with Uber or try to drive traffic away from Uber.
> - Resell Uber's services.
> - Aggregate Uber with competitors.
> - Store or aggregate Uber's data, except as expressly permitted by Uber.
> - Slander or disparage Uber.